# How do I load in string values into dictionary with keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary

In Python 3 I've created an empty dictionary with the following keys:

```
default_value = ''

sq = dict.fromkeys(['Num','ID','Cognome','Data','altezza','V6','spec_role','V8','Nome','Ruolo','nick','trasf','straniero','pict','V15','V16','V17'],default_value)
```

I don't know how to load values from a string like this sequentially:

```
line = '1   LUC-TOR Tortuga 10/13/1991              LUC-TOR Luca    2   Tortuga         33524.7 '
```

to obtain:

```
mydict = { 
    "Num": 1,
    "ID": LUC-TOR,
    "Cognome": Tortuga,
    "Data": 10/13/1991
    "altezza":
    "V6": 
    "spec_role":
    "V8":
    "Nome": Luca
    "Ruolo": 2
    "nick": Tortuga
    "trasf":
    "straniero":
    "pict":
    "V15":
    "V16":
    "V17": 33524.7
}
```

What is the best pythonic way to do it?

Comment: I've forgot to say that the string is tab separated. For that I can use the string.split method as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
keys = ['Num','ID','Cognome','Data','altezza','V6','spec_role','V8','Nome','Ruolo','nick','trasf','straniero','pict','V15','V16','V17']

values = line.split('\t')

mydict = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

`zip` produces a sequence of tuple pairs, e.g. `('Num', '1')`, `('ID', 'LUC-TOR')`, ...

If you wanted you could also have a list of types to convert the values to:

```
types = [int, str, str, date, ...]

mydict = {key: _type(value)
          for key, value, _type in zip(keys, values, types)}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I didn't know the zip function.

Answer (score 3):

Use `split()` to split the string into a list of values. Then you can combine it with the list of keys.

```
keys = ['Num','ID','Cognome','Data','altezza','V6','spec_role','V8','Nome','Ruolo','nick','trasf','straniero','pict','V15','V16','V17']
my_dict = dict(zip(keys, line.split('\t')))
```

Answer (score 0):

use `zip()` and `split()`:

```
keys = ['Num','ID','Cognome','Data','altezza','V6','spec_role','V8','Nome','Ruolo','nick','trasf','straniero','pict','V15','V16','V17']
mydict = dict(zip(keys, line.split('\t')))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert your line to array, there is my func:

```
def convert_to_array(value):
    result_line = ''
    white_space_prev=False
    for el in line:
        if el!=' ':
            if white_space_prev:
                result_line+=' '+el
            else:
                result_line+=el
            white_space_prev=False
        else:
            white_space_prev=True
    return result_line.split(' ')
line = '1    LUC-TOR Tortuga 10/13/1991              LUC-TOR Luca    2   Tortuga         33524.7 '
print(convert_to_array(line))
```

result:

```
['1', 'LUC-TOR', 'Tortuga', '10/13/1991', 'LUC-TOR', 'Luca', '2', 'Tortuga', '33524.7']
```